# Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (6).のエラーを直したいです．

Tags: python, pytorch

機械学習のコードを実装しており，LogisticRegression(nn.Module)をモデルにしています．
損失lossの計算時に配列のサイズのミスマッチに関するエラーがでます．xはshape=[1,64],yはshape=[1,6]です．
エラーに該当するfor文内はxはshape=[64],yはshape=[6]です．どなたか，このエラーの直し方をご教示下さい．よろしくお願い致します．
'''エラー文'''

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet-master/bindsnet/nextrsnn.py", line 101, in <module>
loss = criterion(output.squeeze(-1),  y.long())
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 948, in forward
ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2422, in cross_entropy
return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2216, in nll_loss
.format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
 ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (6).
```

'''コードとエラー箇所'''

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from bindsnet.network import Network
from bindsnet.network.nodes import Input, LIFNodes
from bindsnet.network.topology import Connection
from bindsnet.network.monitors import Monitor

# モデルの定義
class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

     def forward(self, x,):
        x = x.view(-1, 64)
        return self.linear(x)
 # ネットワーク作成
 input_size = 64
 num_classes = 6
 time = 64     
 network = Network(dt=1.0)
 _BATCH_SIZE = 300
 # ニューロンのレイヤー 5層作成
 inpt = Input(n=64, sum_input=True)
 middle = LIFNodes(n=40, trace=True, sum_input=True)
 center = LIFNodes(n=40, trace=True, sum_input=True)
 final = LIFNodes(n=40, trace=True, sum_input=True)
 out = LIFNodes(n=6, sum_input=True)

 # レイヤー同士の接続
 inpt_middle = Connection(source=inpt, target=middle, wmin=0, wmax=1e-1)
 middle_center = Connection(source=middle, target=center, wmin=0, wmax=1e-1)
 center_final = Connection(source=center, target=final, wmin=0, wmax=1e-1)
 final_out = Connection(source=final, target=out, wmin=0, wmax=1e-1)

 # 全てのレイヤー5層をネットワークに接続
 network.add_layer(inpt, name='A')
 network.add_layer(middle, name='B')
 network.add_layer(center, name='C')
 network.add_layer(final,  name='D')
 network.add_layer(out, name='E')

 forward_connection = Connection(source=inpt, target=middle, w=0.05 + 0.1*torch.randn(inpt.n, middle.n))
 network.add_connection(connection=forward_connection, source="A", target="B")
 forward_connection = Connection(source=middle, target=center, w=0.05 + 0.1*torch.randn(middle.n, center.n))
 network.add_connection(connection=forward_connection, source="B", target="C")
 forward_connection = Connection(source=center, target=final, w=0.05 + 0.1*torch.randn(center.n, final.n))
 network.add_connection(connection=forward_connection, source="C", target="D")
 forward_connection = Connection(source=final, target=out, w=0.05 + 0.1*torch.randn(final.n, out.n))
 network.add_connection(connection=forward_connection, source="D", target="E")
 recurrent_connection = Connection(source=out, target=out, w=0.025*(torch.eye(out.n)-1),)
 network.add_connection(connection=recurrent_connection, source="E", target="E")

 # 入力と出力層Monitorを作成(電圧とスパイクを記録)
 inpt_monitor = Monitor(obj=inpt, state_vars=("s", "v"), time=500,)
 middle_monitor = Monitor(obj=inpt, state_vars=("s", "v"), time=500,)
 center_monitor = Monitor(obj=inpt, state_vars=("s", "v"), time=500,)
 final_monitor = Monitor(obj=inpt, state_vars=("s", "v"), time=500,)
 out_monitor = Monitor(obj=inpt, state_vars=("s", "v"), time=500,)

 # Monitorをネットワークに接続
 network.add_monitor(monitor=inpt_monitor, name="A")
 network.add_monitor(monitor=middle_monitor, name="B")
 network.add_monitor(monitor=center_monitor, name="C")
 network.add_monitor(monitor=final_monitor, name="D")
 network.add_monitor(monitor=out_monitor, name="E")

 for l in network.layers:
     m = Monitor(network.layers[l], state_vars=['s'], time=time)
     network.add_monitor(m, name=l)

  # トレーニングデータをロード 　x = shape[1,64] y = [1,6]
  npzfile = np.load("C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
  x = npzfile['x']
  y = npzfile['y']
  # tensor型に変換
  x = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
  y = torch.from_numpy(y).float()

  training_pairs = []
  for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x.view(-1, 64), y)):
      inputs = {'A': x.repeat(time, 1), 'E_b': torch.ones(time, 1)}
      network.run(inputs=inputs, time=time)
      training_pairs.append([network.monitors['E'].get('s').sum(-1), y])
      network.reset_state_variables()

     if (i + 1) % 50 == 0: print('Train progress: (%d / 500)' % (i + 1))
     if (i + 1) == 500: print(); break

     model = LogisticRegression(input_size, num_classes); criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()   
     optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    # スパイクとラベルのトレーニング
    for epoch in range(6):
          for i, (s, y) in enumerate(training_pairs):
              optimizer.zero_grad(); output = model(s.float()).view(-1,6)
              loss = criterion(output.squeeze(-1),  y.long()) ☚ここです
              loss.backward(); optimizer.step()

    test_pairs = []
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x.view(-1, 64), y)):
        inputs = {'A': x.repeat(time, 1), 'E_b': torch.ones(time, 1)}
        network.run(inputs=inputs, time=time)
        test_pairs.append([network.monitors['E'].get('s').sum(-1), y])
        network.reset_state_variables()

    if (i + 1) % 50 == 0: print('Test progress: (%d / 500)' % (i + 1))
    if (i + 1) == 500: print(); break

    correct, total = 0, 0
    for s, y in test_pairs:
        output = model(s); _, predicted = torch.max(output.data.unsueeze(0), 1)
        total += 1; correct += int(predicted == y.long())

    print('Accuracy of logistic regression on 500 test examples: %2f %%\n ' % (100 * correct / total))
     torch.save({
        'epoch': epoch,
        'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
        'loss': loss,
        }, "C:/Users/name/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet-master/bindsnet/pytorchsession")
```

Answer (score 1):

エラー出力に `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (6).` とあるように、input, target のバッチサイズが異なるようです。

ドキュメントにあるように、バッチサイズを表す0次元目のサイズは同じである必要があります。
[torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss - PyTorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)

---

よりよい回答を得るために、こちらも参考にしてみてください。

- [良い質問をするには？ - stackoverflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方 - stackoverflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)